# ¿Cómo ocultar varias columnas usando Apps Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando ocultar las columnas S a AE (S:AE), la última columna activa es BF, pero cuando corro el código me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> Those columns are out of bounds.,

pero no sé por qué:

```
function Hide() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var origen = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('IFT');
  var hoja = spreadsheet.insertSheet();
  var rangoIFT = origen.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  var rangoNuevo = hoja.getRange(1, 1).activate();

  var column = hoja.getMaxColumns();
  var ct = 19;
 
  rangoIFT.copyTo(rangoNuevo, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
 
  /*Lo que se pega de la hoja llamada IFT a la hoja nueva es una tabla y otros valores que van desde la columna A hasta la columna BF, pero en las columnas S hasta la AE hay valores que quiero ocultar */

  /*I tried this way too -----> sheet.hideColumns(19,12)*/

  hoja.hideColumns(ct, (column-ct));
  
};
```

Comment: Faltan detalles ¿Cuántas columna o cuál es la última columna de la hoja activa?

Comment: La última columna activa es BF y quiero ocultar las columnas S:AE, pero por alguna razón me sale ese error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los archivos por default tienen un numero inicial de columnas son las letras, en general son 26 pero puedes agregar y demas, lo que pasa es que le estas diciendo que a partir de la columna 19 oculte 12 lo que es mas de las 26 (asumiendo que tendas ese numero por default) y por eso lanza ese mensaje, porque no que no existen. Con getMaxColumns() puedes obtener el numero maximo de columnas y validar.

```
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var columns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
var to_hide = 19;
sheet.hideColumns(to_hide,(columns - to_hide));
```

asumiendo en el ejemplo claro que el numero maximo de columnas sea mayor a el indice donde va a empezar

Comment: use el código que me propusiste, pero no me funcionó. Igual edité el código a como lo tengo para que se pueda visualizar mejor y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Lo que hace el código con la ayuda que me propusiste sí oculta los valores, pero solo hasta la columna Z y aún me quedaría pendiente ocultar desde la columna AA hasta la columna AE.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia

```
var column = hoja.getMaxColumns();
```

por

```
var column = 31; // Índice de las columna AE
```

y

```
hoja.hideColumns(column, (ct-column));
```

por

```
hoja.hideColumns(ct, (ct-column + 1));
```

Lo anterior porque el primer parámetro de `hideColums` debe ser el índice de la columna inicial y el segundo parámetro el número de columnas a ocultar.

Comment: Cambié el código exactamente como me lo indicaste, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error: Those columns are out of bounds.

Comment: @DanielContreras Por favor agrega el mensaje textual de error a la pregunta.